# Чтение определенной переменной php

Tags: php, php7

Есть файл index.php в нем храниться n-ое количество переменных и визуальная часть страницы. Из данного файла, необходимо в текущий файл достать только значение переменной $title и больше ничего. Так как в файле есть визуальная часть, то метод include и подобные не подходят насколько я понимаю.

Comment: Код файла не помешало бы опубликовать.

Comment: вынесите $title в отдельный файл и подключите везде где нужно.

Comment: Так не получиться, так как таких файлов море и я их перебираю циклом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас возникают подобные задачи, значит явно имеются проблемы с дизайном/архитектурой приложения.

Одним из выходов в данной ситуации будет использование буферизации вывода. 
Собственно далее пример кода  из документации [(Пример #6 Использование буферизации вывода для включения файла PHP в строку)](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php)

```
$string = get_include_contents('somefile.php');

function get_include_contents($filename) {
    if (is_file($filename)) {
        ob_start();
        include $filename;
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
    return false;
}
```

в вашем случае же надо будет просто вызывать `ob_clean()` и вернуть значение нужной подключенной переменной.

Comment: Спасибо Вы правы